# Show that $ |\nabla^2(u)|^2\geq \frac{1}{n}|\Delta (u)|^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Show that $ |\nabla^2(u)|^2\geq \frac{1}{n}|\Delta (u)|^2$ where $u$ is a solution of $-\Delta u=\lambda u$. I am not getting how this $\frac{1}{n}$ term  coming in this inequality.

Comment: Your notation is unclear. Often, people use $\nabla^2 := \nabla \cdot \nabla$ to indicate the Laplacian $\Delta$. In that case, your inequality is trivially satisfied for $n\geq 1$.
I assume the left-hand-side should be $(\nabla u) \cdot (\nabla u)$? Furthermore, what does the absolute value denote? The norm corresponding to the $L^2$ scalar product? And also, what is $n$? I assume that $u= u(\boldsymbol x)$ with $\boldsymbol x \in  \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.math.uci.edu/~zlu/publications/2006-2010/28.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjN1cLe76z5AhUUguYKHVBECmIQFnoECBUQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3bQ0iSmnvRqjmSF2edJpwd      This is actually used to bound the first eigenvalue in Riemannian manifold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the paper you reference, $\nabla^2 u$  is denoting to the Hessian of $u$ and, in coordinates, we have that $$ \vert \nabla^2 u \vert^2= \sum_{i,j,k,l}g^{ij}g^{kl}\nabla_{ik}u \nabla_{jl}u. $$ Here $g_{ij}$ is the metric, $g^{ij}$ the inverse of the metric, and $\nabla$ is the Riemannian connection. The authors obtain the inequality by using the Cauchy-Schwartz as follows:\begin{align*}
(\Delta u )^2 &= \bigg ( \sum_{i,j} g^{ij}\nabla_{ij}u \bigg )^2 \\
&= \bigg ( \sum_i 1 \cdot \bigg ( \sum_j g^{ij}\nabla_{ij}u \bigg ) \bigg )^2 \\
&\leqslant \bigg ( \sum_i 1 \bigg ) \cdot  \sum_{i,j=1}^n (g^{ij}\nabla_{ij}u)^2 \\ &\leqslant n \vert \nabla^2 u \vert^2.
\end{align*} In particular, this inequality is valid for all $C^2$ functions not just solutions to $-\Delta u = \lambda u $.